# Java! How to display the correct and incorrect answered questions after user finish answering the questions

Tags: java

I have a Java program that asks user questions and totals their scores. I am trying to display the correct total of answered questions at the end of the program. However, I have no idea how to, can some please help me! 
Here is an example of how my code looks like l! But this is not my actual code this is from another source!

```
Import java.util.Scanner;


public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // The array of questions.
        String questions[] = {
                "Plants derive most of their dry mass from the air.",
                "Aluminium is the most common metal in the Earth's crust.",
                "Vitamin C has be shown to prevent colds.",
                "We lose the most heat through our heads.",
                "Dogs are unable to digest chocolate.",
                "Apple pips contain cyanide.",
                "Cholesterol is a nat
                "When you're on a diet, you lose weight by oxidising fat to a gas and exhaling it.",
                "Human beings are unable to sense when the oxygen level of the air is low.",
                "Most of the Y chromosome is passed unchanged from father to son" };

        // The array of answers. The entries correspond to the questions.
        boolean answers[] = { true, true, false, false, false, true, false,
                              true, true, true };

        // Display the opening text.
        System.out.println("Answer each of the following questions with 't' (true) or 'f' (false)");

        // We'll use this to get user input.
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Add up the user's score here as we go along.
        int score = 0;

        // The is the index into the questions array and the answers array.
        int questionNumber = 0;

        // Create a blank line.
        System.out.println();

        // The do-while loop will keep running while questionNumber is less
        // than the question array length.
        do {
            // Display the question
            System.out.println(questions[questionNumber]);

            // Display a little prompt to make it clearer that the user has to
            // enter something.
            System.out.print("> ");

            // Get the user's answer.
            String userAnswer = input.nextLine();

            // Check that the user has entered t or f.
            if (!userAnswer.equals("t") && !userAnswer.equals("f")) {
                System.out.println("Please enter t for true or f for false.\n");

                // Invalid input!
                // Skip the rest of this loop iteration and ask the same question again.
                continue;
            }

            // Check the answer.
            if (userAnswer.equals("t") && answers[questionNumber] == true) {
                // If the answer's t and the right answer is "true", the answer was correct.
                score++;
                System.out.println("correct\n");
            } else if (userAnswer.equals("f") && answers[questionNumber] == false) {
                // If the answer's f and the correct answer is "false", the answer was correct.
                System.out.println("correct\n");
                score++;
            }
            else {
                // Wrong answer!
                System.out.println("incorrect!\n");
            }

            // Now we can move to the next question when we go round the loop again.
            questionNumber++;

        } while (questionNumber < questions.length); // end of do-while.

        // This isn't really necessary, but closing the Scanner prevents a warning icon in Eclipse.
        input.close();

        // Tell the user their score.
        System.out.println("You scored: " + score);

        // Rank the score! Only one of the alternatives below will execute.
        // Java will check them in order from top to bottom.
        if(score < 5) {
            // Less than 5 -- not so good.
            System.out.println("Hmmm, maybe you're the artistic type. Try the test again!");
        }
        else if(score < 8) {
            // The score wasn't less than 5, but it IS less than 8.
            System.out.println("Not bad! But have another go.");
        }
        else if(score <= 9) {
            // The score wasn't less than 8, but it IS less than, or equal to, 9.
            System.out.println("Pretty good! But no perfect. Try again!");
        }
        else {
            // The score was more than 9 -- must be 10 because we've only got 10 questions.
            System.out.println("You're a certified science genius!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This code came from [Cave of Programming](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/java-exercises/java-exercise-challenge-science-quiz.html) (visible when clicking on the button "Click for example solution"). It is most definitely not your code.

Comment: Yeah bro am working on something exactly like it! So i found it as a free source code, its a free world bro enjoy it while it last️! Figure out why not post it as an example u knw what am trying to say ryt?

Comment: Am using my phone here and my code is in my system u knw! I hope thats not a problem u knw!

Comment: There are rules in this site. One of them is that when you bring code from some source, you should always refer to the source. That is, you should not say "my code" (which I see you fixed), but you should also say "This is from this author at this place" - if it's on the web, give a link. Otherwise this is plagiarism - you are using artwork which is not yours.

Comment: Alright i will keep that in mind sir. Thanks for all the help anyway! I appreciate, this is actually a good place for young programmers like me, Thanks once again sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list and add the question nummer when the user has answered the question correctly.
Before your do-while-loop you have to add

```
ArrayList<Integer> correctQuestions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then in your do-while-loop you have to add when the answer is correct

```
correctQuestions.add(questionNumber);
```

At the end of you program (outside the do-while-loop) you can make the output like this:

```
System.out.println("You answered the following questions correctly");
for (int k : correctQuestions) {
   System.out.println(questions[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare a boolean array containing user answers in your class:

```
public boolean[] userAnswers = new boolean[questions.length]; //remove the access modifier if you want to declare the array inside main instead of the class
```

Now in your do-while loop, after parsing the user input, do this:

```
userAnswers[questionNumber] = userAnswer.equals("t");
```

Outside of your do-while loop (after you close the `Scanner`), do the following to print all the questions and the user's answer:

```
for (int i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("User answered \"" + userAnswers[i] + "\" on question " + (i + 1) + ": " + questions[i]);
}
```